# Why learn Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

One of my college professors said that ruby on rails is used a lot for web, and I'm wondering how much Ruby on Rails is actually used vs JQuery, Node.js, PHP, etc. Also, what are the benefits?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing some stuff:

- Ruby on Rails is a framework to create server side web applications using the Ruby language
- jQuery is a client side JavaScript library that simplifies writing JavaScript web clients
- Node.js is a server for the execution of server side JavaScript, thus providing a server version of JavaScript
- PHP is a language popular for server side web application development

Thus: Ruby on Rails is a mature framework which offers a template engine, MVC architecture, a mapper between language objects and some relational database and a routing facility between URIs and controller.
Similiar designed frameworks exist for many programming languages / environments, e.g. Django for Python, or see [Rails-inspired PHP frameworks](https://h3rald.com/articles/rails-inspired-php-frameworks/) in case of PHP.

About its popularity, see e.g. http://hotframeworks.com/

Benefits: IMHO it is a very elegant framework and as the plethora of inspired frameworks shows, has found many developers who like it. 
The concepts and techniques learned here might also turn out to be useful when working with other modern frameworks.

And I should note as well, that there are web applications that need less features, e.g. see the [Sinatra framework](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) for a lighter alternative.

Answer (score -1):

> Also, what are the benefits?

There are a lot of things that websites have in common, e.g. html pages with forms, various javascript features, database interactions, security issues, logging in, etc.  If you start from scratch, and try to program all those things yourself, it will be difficult and time consuming, and most likely your code will be full of exploitable security holes.

The other option is to use a web framework.  Ruby on Rails is a web framework for the ruby programming language.  All the various server side programming languages, such as ruby, python, php, perl, java, etc., have web frameworks(and usually many different frameworks to choose from!).  A lot of smart people have come up with the best code for various things that websites need, and you get to use their code for free in your website.

The disadvantage of frameworks is that they are often large and complex, e.g. Ruby on Rails, Java Servlets+JSP, so it can take awhile to learn how to use them.  Even then, you will probably not have a good grasp of their inner workings, so you are always sort of feeling around in the dark trying to get them to work the way you want them to.  It's sort of like trying to push a large boulder which is at rest to another spot of your choosing:  sometimes the boulder rolls cleanly into position, and other times the boulder seems to have a mind of its own and wanders off course.